# Python: Verify Credit Card digits

Tags: python, validation, numbers, rules, credit-card

I  need to implement a function called “verify” that takes a single parameter
called “number” and then checks the following rules:

1. The first digit must be a 4.
2. The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit; keep in mind that these
   are separated by a dash since the format is ####-####-####.
3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4.
4. If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth
   digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def verify(number): # do not change this line!

  list_number=list(number.split(''))
  Check=false

# write your code here so that it verifies the card number

    if list_number[0]==4:
    if list_number[3]==list_number[5]+1:
    if list_number.sum() % 4==0:
    if int(str(list_number[0])+str(list_number[1]))+int(str(list_number[7])+str(list_number[8])) ==100:

    Check = true

    else:
    check = false

input = "4094-3460-2754" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output
```

Comment: Apart from not being sure if my code is correct I also get this error: "Error on line 8:
    if list_number[0]==4:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent"

Comment: Your else isn't indented properly and none of your if statements have a body..... Your code is far from being runable. Your ifs are also further indented than the code before it.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need. each if statement in the function corresponds to condition that you have specified.

```
def verify(number):  # do not change this line!
    number_string = number.replace("-", "")
    list_number = [int(n) for n in number_string]

    if not list_number[0] == 4:
        return False

    if not list_number[3] - list_number[4] == 1:
        return False

    if not sum(list_number) % 4 == 0:
        return False

    if not int(number_string[0:2]) + int(number_string[6:8]) == 100:
        return False

    return True


input = "4094-3460-2754"
output = verify(input)
print(output)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few fundamental errors in your code. I will list them down for you:

1. Boolean values start with a capital
2. there are no indentations after your if and else statements
3. Your output will always print none as your function does not return anything.

````
def verify(number):
    list_number=list(number)
    if list_number[0]==4 and list_number[3]==list_number[5]+1 and list_number.sum() % 4==0 and int(str(list_number[0])+str(list_number[1]))+int(str(list_number[7])+str(list_number[8])) ==100:
        return True
     else:
        return False
input = "4094-3460-2754"
output = verify(input) 
print(output)```
````

Answer (score -1):

Your code is way to poorly written

```
list_number = "4094-3460-2754"
list_number = list_number.replace('-','')

if list_number[0]=='4' and int(list_number[3])==int(list_number[5])+1 and list_number.sum() % 4==0 and int(list_number[0])+int(list_number[1])==int(list_number[7])+int(list_number[8]):
    check = True
else:
    check = False
```